PHP FATAL ERROR, errors saying theres a duplicate class but there isnt
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use in C:\Users\joshu\laraveljobs_app\database\migrations\create_users_table.php on line 7
This is the error code, I have checked and checked and cant seem to find any duplicate :(
PS C:\Users\joshu\laraveljobs_app> php artisan migrate

   INFO  Running migrations.

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use in C:\Users\joshu\laraveljobs_app\database\migrations\create_users_table.php on line 7

   Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError 

  Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use

  at database\migrations\create_users_table.php:7
      3▕ use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
      4▕ use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
      5▕ use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
      6▕
  ➜   7▕ class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
      8▕ {
      9▕     /**
     10▕      * Run the migrations.
     11▕      *


   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException 

  Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use

  at database\migrations\create_users_table.php:7
      3▕ use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
      4▕ use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
      5▕ use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
      6▕
  ➜   7▕ class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
      8▕ {
      9▕     /**
     10▕      * Run the migrations.
     11▕      *

  1   vendor\filp\whoops\src\Whoops\Run.php:510
      Whoops\Run::handleError("Cannot declare class CreateUsersTable, because the name is already in use", "C:\Users\joshu\laraveljobs_app\database\migrations\create_users_table.php")

  2   [internal]:0
      Whoops\Run::handleShutdown() ```


I have scanned and also used find all references but it only brings up one line. I have also tried 

findstr /s "AddRoleToUsersTable" 

again only one line. 


Can you make a composer dump or php artisan cache:clear in the root of your project?
If not, manually clear the cache.
The string that you need to find is 'CreateUsersTable' instead of 'AddRoleToUsersTable'

Sorry the string I had pasted was another line i was trying to find, I had used the string grab for "CreateUsersTable. I have also cleared the cache manually multiple times.

This is the reason why they created anonymous migrations these days. But since you're probably using a very old Laravel version... rename the class in your migration, then re-run the migrations. If it tells your newly renamed class is also duplicate, then something's just wrong
